# How can I execute php from a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

How would I go about executing a php-script from a javascript-function?

```
<?php if ( isset( $results['errorMessage'] ) ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript>somemethod(<?php echo $results['errorMessage'] ?>)    </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Sorry for the bad formatting - not sure how to use code in this editor :S

Comment: Your code looks like setting Javascript from PHP, rather than the other way around

Comment: Looks like you're missing some quotes. You are echoing a string to pass to a Javascript method, but if you look at the generated Javascript code you will find that the string is unquoted and will therefore most likely be syntactically incorrect. E.g. you need to generate `somemethod('this is a message')` but you are actually generating `somemethod(this is a message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an HTTP REQUEST from JavaScript to call a remote PHP page/script.

The way you are trying to do it is not possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't!
Javascript executes on client-side (ie. client's browser) and PHP executes on the server.

What you can do is to make an Ajax request to your PHP script and do something according to the results.

Answer (score 0):

i use this one to send request with javascript and its works perfectly :

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
        var xmlHttp = null;

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

and the html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="log.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <a href="" onclick="httpGet('message.php?url=http://bizzare.com/?id=1')">Get Message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of a template your example just needs to tweaking to generate the correct JavaScript on the page:

To fix this example you could try

```
<?php if ( isset( $results['errorMessage'] ) ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript>
        somemethod(<?php echo "'" . $results['errorMessage'] . "'" ?>);
    </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

But as other answers suggest, it may better to go down the ajax route. Generating JavaScript is often a bad design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying somethig like call a simple JS function with a message?

```
<?php 
   if(isset($results['errorMessage'])){
      echo '<script type="text/javascript>somemethod("'.$results['errorMessage'].'")</script>';
   }
?>
```